# Exporting plot png using cairo

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

I generally have been exporting pngs of my plots, by using ggsave and setting type to cairo for antialiasing. However, recently I got this error:

```
Using ragg device as default. Ignoring `type` and `antialias` arguments
```

I'm not sure what I did or changed. This has been my code for exporting the last generated plot as a png to the wd:

```
ggsave(filename = 'X.png', 
+        dpi = 300, 
+        type = 'cairo',
+        width = 30, height = 15, units = 'in')
```

I have some issues with ragg, so I'd like to use cairo again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ragg package solved the issue. I can now export as before.